# change style background property by using getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom, simple-html-dom

How can I change my textbox color if I hit the error function? I try the following code but it's not working only the error message will display.

```
<Script>
function fnName(ID)
{
    var flag = true;
    if(document.mainform.NAME.value == "")
    {
        error_function("Please enter the Name.",ID);
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        release_function(ID)
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
function error_function(message,IDs)
{
        var ID = '"' + IDs + '"';

        document.getElementById("proposererrMsg").innerHTML     = message;
        document.getElementById("proposererrMsg").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById(ID).style.background  = "#DDDDDD";  //this line not working
         document.getElementById(ID).style.border    = "thin solid red"; // this line not working

}
</script>

 <label id="proposererrMsg" class="errMsg"></label> 
 <input type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" value="<%=NAME%>" onblur="fnName(this.id);" />
```

Comment: `.error { background-color: #ddd }` + `document.getElementById(ID).className = "error";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ID` you use has unnecessary quotes, so you try to reference an element with a nonexistent ID, just use `IDs` parameter directly:

`document.getElementById(IDs).style.background  = "#DDDDDD";`

Comment: can u try look at my border ? my border is not working

Comment: Use `IDs` instead of `ID` as well.

Comment: may i know why shouldn't i put the double quote for ID? since the default getElementByID("IDNAME"); is quoted

Comment: Quotes mean it's a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals)

Comment: OK thanks again. i put the same IDs for border and it's working. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use [MDN - `backgroundColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript).

```js
<script>
function fnName(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" value="" onblur="fnName(this.id);" /
```

Comment: Why down vote? does this is not working? Have a courtesy to explain.

Comment: Wasn't me, the code in your answer is correct, but the rationale was probably the lack of explanation why the posted code wasn't working.